Install a loadbalancer and make it work together with rancher
We have an on premise kubernetes cluster running with rancher, on vmware.
Starting the cluster was easy, specify nodes and their resources and press create. Then we can get to the containers running on them by passing through any controlplane.
But rancher being rancher, whenever we add new config settings all nodes are destroyed and new ones created with the new config settings. It's great to see.
But what follows is is that these nodes have new ip addresses! So the old client calls to the cluster dont work anymore and we need to update to the new IP.
An external loadbalancer is supposed to fix that but how do we install and configure a loadbalancer in vmware so that iorks together with the rancher VMs? Does rancher call that LB to update with the new ip-addresses?
